# Is functionalism a significant improvement on behaviourism with respect to behaviour?

Tags: qualia, functionalism, hilary-putnam, behaviorism

Functionalism appears to be free of many of the issues that behaviourism faces, however is it all positive? Is there any objection at all to Functionalism being such an improvement in respect to behaviour?

Comment: Behaviourism is deeply discredited, so sure, an approach that isn't is going. to be 'better'. Searle's Chinese Room is a classic objection. Chalmers & Penrose are among those who think it can't work

Comment: Hello, again. What do you mean by 'significant improvement'? What do you mean by 'all positive'? What exactly constitutes an 'improvement'? See my comments on your other question for suggested ways of improving your question. It helps to focus your question to avoid open-ended speculative questions.

Comment: Again, here's [SEP: functionalism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/functionalism/).

Comment: Don't give up. You're asking good questions, just too broad for our site. Here's [SEP: behaviorism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/behaviorism/).